# How to access class' controller variable in angular material $mdDialog.confirm()/prompt()?

Tags: angularjs, angular-meteor, angularjs-material

Is it possible to change `this.status` after confirming dialog with either answer?

```
class ComponentCtrl {
    constructor($scope, $reactive, $mdDialog) {
        'ngInject';

        $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;

        this.status = "Click button below to set status";
    }

    showDialog(event) {
        this.$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
            // Yes
            console.log('I like dogs');
            this.status = 'I like dogs'; //doesn't work
        }, function() {
            // No
            console.log('I love cats');
            this.status = 'I love cats'; //doesn't work
        });
    }
}
```

The way around is to define custom dialog (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog) with options:

```
locals: { ParentCtrl: this },
bindToController: true
```

In case above you can have access to all variables/functions of parent controller but it involves a lot more coding instead of using ngMaterial's shorthand for quick dialogs.

Comment: Is this what you want? - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/JKBqYN?editors=1010#0

Comment: @camden_kid The above won't work if you use ES6 class syntax and Meteor. Solution is below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to use `this.$bindToContext`.

More info:
http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.11/reactive-context and
http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/handling-files-with-collectionfs - "20.15  Handle file selection"

```
class ComponentCtrl {
    constructor($scope, $reactive, $mdDialog) {
        'ngInject';

        $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        this.$mdDialog = $mdDialog;

        this.status = "Click button below to set status";
    }

    showDialog(event) {
        this.$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(this.$bindToContext(() => {
            // Yes
            console.log('I like dogs');
            this.status = 'I like dogs'; //working now
        }), this.$bindToContext(() => {
            // No
            console.log('I love cats');
            this.status = 'I love cats'; //working now
        }));
    }
}
```